# create an html select via jquery with a while statement or similar

Tags: jquery, html

How do I write an html select statement via jquery?

Let's say I've got this in mind:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="401">401</option>
  <option value="402">402</option>
  <option value="403">403</option>
</select>
```

And I need it to be written from jquery.

I've tried this (without success)

```
$('#div2').append('<select name = "myshield2" id="myshieldSelect2">');
var i = 400;
while (i < '410') {
   // do some code
   $('#div1').append('<option name="asdf" value = "1">Hey ' + i + ' is the value!</option>');
   i++;
}
$('#div2').append('</select>');
```

Comment: you mix div1 and div2 inside your code. plus are you certain `<div id="div2">` exists in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using append jQuery appends the actual html elements instead of the html, its not like writing to a stream of HTML.

Also, appending to HTML attached to the document itself in small parts is extremely inefficient.  The following variation of your code should work and should be much faster:

```
var html = [];
html[html.length] = '<select name = "myshield2" id="myshieldSelect2">';
var i = 400;
while (i < '410') {
   // do some code
   html[html.length] = '<option name="asdf" value = "1">Hey ' + i + ' is the value!    </option>';
   i++;
}
html[html.length] = '</select>';
$('#div1').append(html.join(''));
```

Here's an example of it in action: [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/ozidaz)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div1').append('<option name="asdf" value = "1">Hey ' + i....');
```

is wrong It should be

```
$('#myshieldSelect2').append('<option name="asdf" ....');
```

Completed it is:

```
$('#div2').append('<select name = "myshield2" id="myshieldSelect2">');
var i = 400;
while (i < '410') 
   $('#myshieldSelect2').append('<option name="asdf" value = "1">Hey ' + i++ + '...');
```